# How can I share the dashboard to client in QlikSense

Tags: business-intelligence, dashboard, qliksense

I am new to Qlik sense. I've created interactive dashboard in QlikSense. How I can share the same interactive dashboard to client place in the web browser.

Comment: Are you running a full instance or just the local desktop version?

Comment: Am running qliksense in Cloud (Free)

Answer (score 5):

Think you have 3 options:

- **Qlik Sense Desktop** - if you develop in QS Desktop the only option here is to send the `qvf` file to the customer and if they have QS installed to import it - **no web browser**
- **Qlik Sense Server** - if you are developing in QS Server you can create login for the customer(s) and publish the app to a stream to which the customer have access and send them the link **(be aware that this will consume license from your pool)** **- web browser**
- **Qlik Sense Cloud** - if you are registered for Qlik Sense Cloud you can upload your app there and share it (with up to 5 people in the Free Tier, or unlimited people on the paid Business Tier) **- web browser**

Comment: Thanks, I am using Qlik Sense Cloud Free tier.

Answer (score 0):

### Managing users in Qlik Cloud

Sharing apps

---

You can use Qlik Cloud to share your apps with a limited number of other users.

When you share with another user, all the apps in your stream are shared. It is not possible to share only an individual app with a particular user.
Do the following:

1. Click Share.
2. Enter the e-mail address of the user that you want to share your
   apps with.
3. Click Submit.

The user receives an e-mail, and may register to gain access to your apps.

> The number on the Share button indicates how many more users you can
>   share with. Stop sharing apps with an individual user

You can stop sharing apps with an individual user.

Do the following:

1. Click the X in the upper-left corner of the profile box of the user
   you want to stop sharing with.
2. In the dialog that is displayed, confirm that you want to stop
   sharing apps with that user.

An e-mail is sent to notify the user that they no longer have access to your apps.

> The number on the Share button increments to indicate that there is an
>   additional share available.

Here's the [sauce](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/1.1/Subsystems/Desktop/Content/Cloud/ManageUsersInCloud.htm)